# HTML5/JS canvas displaying pictures

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having trouble displaying pictures on my canvas, especially when using Chrome.

I have a method that is called to draw a portrait (name, img, borders), but `context.drawImage()` doesn't seem to be working in Chrome. Any solutions?

```
Portrait.prototype.draw = function (context, x, y, tX, tY) {
    context.save();
    context.translate( tX, tY );        
    context.fillStyle = 'blue';
    context.strokeStyle = 'black';
    context.strokeRect(x, y, 160, 200);
    context.fillRect(x, y, 160, 200);
    context.stroke(); 
    // adding the image
    context.beginPath();          
    var img = new Image();
    var link = this.getImageUrl();
    img.src = link; 
    //context.drawImage(img,x+5,y+5);  //works mozzila      
    img.onload = function () { context.drawImage(img,x+5,y+5); }  
    // partial work chrome but on refresh displays e.g two different portrait images in turn in a random portrait (if multiple portraits on canvas)          
    // text box
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = '#ffffff';
    context.fillRect(x+5,y + 165,150,30);
    // text
    context.beginPath();
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    var n = this.getName();
    context.font = "25px Aerial";
    context.fillText(n,x+5,y+190); // should give the name      
    context.restore();
};
```

Comment: The getImageURL() works, its a method that returns the correct url of the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing `img.onload` a function which will be executed asynchronously, meaning the other lines of code will proceed before it's done. Wrap the entire "draw" in your image.onload function.

```
Portrait.prototype.draw = function (context, x, y, tX, tY) {
    var img = new Image();
    var link = this.getImageUrl();
    img.src = link; 

    img.onload = function () {
        context.save();
        context.translate( tX, tY );        
        context.fillStyle = 'blue';
        context.strokeStyle = 'black';
        context.strokeRect(x, y, 160, 200);
        context.fillRect(x, y, 160, 200);
        context.stroke();
        context.drawImage(img,x+5,y+5);
        //...

    }
};
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver ! I though it may be asynchronous but I didn't know how to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: Oh btw I had to remove the var n = this.getName(); because it could not refer to the correct objects

Comment: You can keep it, just add `var self = this;` as the first line of the draw function and write `var n = self.getName()` instead!